# How to send info to the layout?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, directoryservices

I want to create a function that sends information to the layout every time.

Now I execute some queries in the layout to get the name and the user with `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and a query to the linked server in the Database, but now I want to create a "Constructor" in the Controller that sends me the info to the View.

I hope you can help me :D or give me an example.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. And in what sense are you using the word "constructor"?

Comment: You don't send anything to views in the constructor. You do it in a controller action. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview

Comment: Hey, can you edit in an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send information/data to the layout page then you can use the session for it.
In my project, I used Session variables and I got the result as expected. 
Below is code which is written in Action Method of Controller,

```
Session["UserName"] = entity.FirstName + " " + entity.LastName;
```

and LayoutPage,

```
<span class="font-bold">@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString()</span>
```

Comment: Nice! <3 Well now my question is Do i have to create a kind of login to execute the ActionMethod? Because I have to display this info everytime, if it is the case... I have to take the Domain\User and the name from the ActiveDirectory How can I do this  "login" automatically?

Comment: Actually I didn't get your question. But you have to write a logic to execute that ActionMethod.